# Changing url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site like "abc.com/1_en-Application.html . Now i want to change it to abc.com/application.html.

I have .htaccess like

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)_(.*)-(.*).html$ index.php?id=$1&page=$2&lang=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)_(.*)-(.*).html$ index.php?id=$1&lang=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Please help me how can i do this ?

Comment: IS `abc.com/application.html` an actual file or it should be routed to `/index.php` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Add the 3 lines below the existing rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /application.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^application.html$ index.php?id=1&lang=en [L]
```

- If you don't have a real file called `application.html` in the web root directory, this will rewrite the URL and internally direct it to `index.php`
- If `application.html` is a real file, it will be shown instead. In that case, the 3 lines will still work but not necessary to include.